# Microsoft graph events api expand and filter

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am using the `Microsoft.Graph.Beta/5.14.0-preview` SDK to query calendar events and I am migration from an `4.22` version of the SDK. Some of my queries uses `$expand` and `$filter` on expanded properties, but for some reason I can't figure out how to re-write these queryes in the new SDK where the query builder is moved to a configuration on the get part.

My old setup looks like this:

```
client
    .Users[userId]
    .CalendarView
    .Request(queryOptions)
    .Filter(filterQuery)
    .Expand(expandOptions)
    .Select(SelectQuery)
    .GetAsync()
```

And the re-written looks like this:

```
client
    .Users[userId]
    .CalendarView
    .GetAsync(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.QueryParameters.StartDateTime = from;
        cfg.QueryParameters.EndDateTime = to;
        cfg.QueryParameters.Filter = filterQuery;
        cfg.QueryParameters.Select = SelectQuery;
    })
```

But I can't find any option to expand anymore in the new SDK - I also tried just til filter on the nested objects and then look up the event ids, but I can't filter on nested objects without expanding them.

My query that don't work look like this:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/calendarView?startDateTime=2022-12-01T00:00:00&endDateTime=2022-12-31T00:00:00&$select=id&$filter=SingleValueExtendedProperties/any(c: c/Id eq 'String {543ec2fa-e468-4b54-be8e-787c70d4a79f} Name ParentEventId' and c/Value eq 'AAMkADJiZWQxZDVmLTViNDAtNGVjOS1hZjdkLWRlMjVlNTQwYzkzOABGAAAAAADJmx9CKBiKQoBAarsrrol5BwAZTSoj4SE7Rbx0wxVE_m1BAAAAAAENAAAZTSoj4SE7Rbx0wxVE_m1BAAADk9fzAAA=')
```

While the one that works, and does the expand and filter correctly looks like this:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/calendarView?startDateTime=2022-12-01T00:00:00&endDateTime=2022-12-31T00:00:00&$select=id&$filter=SingleValueExtendedProperties/any(c: c/Id eq 'String {543ec2fa-e468-4b54-be8e-787c70d4a79f} Name ParentEventId' and c/Value eq 'AAMkADJiZWQxZDVmLTViNDAtNGVjOS1hZjdkLWRlMjVlNTQwYzkzOABGAAAAAADJmx9CKBiKQoBAarsrrol5BwAZTSoj4SE7Rbx0wxVE_m1BAAAAAAENAAAZTSoj4SE7Rbx0wxVE_m1BAAADk9fzAAA=')&$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq 'String {543ec2fa-e468-4b54-be8e-787c70d4a79f} Name ParentEventId')
```

I am not sure if this is the best way of querying `SingleValueExtendedProperties` but the old setup works - and i can't figure out how to migrate it in the new SDK.

Comment: It seems to me like a bug. For some reason, authors of version 5 have decided not to generate expand query parameter for calendarView endpoint. You should definitely report it as a bug and describe your case when you use expand parameter. https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues

Comment: For checking the query options on the updated SDK version also please refer:https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/upgrade-to-v4.md#query-options-are-now-encoded-by-default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an bug in the SDK metadata: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/1581